# Unexpected "\n" while trying to exec command in paramiko

Tags: paramiko

Okay, so I tried to remove files on remote machine with paramiko. But I'm stuck on this error:

```
 "bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('\n",
 "bash: -c: line 1: `rm -rf /home/server/audio(23).mp3'\n".
```

Code:

```py
self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
self.ssh.load_system_host_keys()

# here is code with establishing ssh connection
# ...
# connection established

path = '/home/server/audio(23).mp3'
com = f"rm {path}"

stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(com)

print(stderr.readlines()) # here I see the error
```

I tried to check is com variable has such substring "\n" but got false as answer so it's not my fault I guess:

`print("\n" in com) # returns false each time`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reformatted your error message a little bit, and the problem should be clearer now:

```
 "bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('\n",
 "bash: -c: line 1: `rm -rf /home/server/audio(23).mp3'\n".
```

As you can see, the `\n` doesn't have anything to do with the error message itself, it's simply just part of the output of the command as returned by paramiko. It's telling you that the unexpected token is **`(`**, not `\n`. When you interpret the error message as an array of python strings, this gets even clearer:

```
 bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
 bash: -c: line 1: `rm -rf /home/server/audio(23).mp3'
```

The correct fix is to use the [`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) function from the Python standard library to escape your file's path before you execute it:

```py
from shlex import quote

path = '/home/server/audio(23).mp3'
com = f"rm {quote(path)}"

stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(com)
```

From the docs:

> Return a shell-escaped version of the string s. The returned value is a string that can safely be used as one token in a shell command line, for cases where you cannot use a list.

Using `shlex.quote` should prevent the shell on the other end (bash, in this case) from getting tripped up by any special characters that may be present in the path (like spaces, parentheses, quotation marks—you name it). Note that `shlex` only works on *Unix* shells. If you want to use paramiko to connect to a *Windows* server over SSH, you'll need a different library. This depends on the server that you're connecting to: it doesn't matter where you run the Python code, it only matters where `self.ssh` ends up pointing to.

Comment: While you are basically right, the correct fix is actually to use SFTP, instead of fabricating shell commands. OP should use `SFTPClient.remove(path)` and no escaping would be needed.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl whether SSH or SFTP is the "right" API for this use-case depends on factors outside of this question, like whether the OP was planning on executing any other commands or operations outside of the smaller SFTP api. Maybe they needed to generate the audio files on the server using e.g. FFMPEG? In that case it would be silly to make a completely separate client connection for SFTP if you already have and are using the SSH connection. In either case, you're welcome to propose that as a second answer if you wish.

Comment: It's not SSH vs SFTP. It's shell vs SFTP. + You do not need a separate connection for SFTP. SFTP can work over the same SSH connection as the shell. + And yes, you are right about the commands. But the thing is that we do not know anything about OP needing to run other commands. All we know is that OP is trying to delete a file (and from past questions, that OP is already using SFTP).